# Invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ with ```rindex``` function

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, c-strings, const-pointer

I want to do something with string using the `index` and `rindex` function under c++17, but when I compile the program, this error poped up:

```
debug.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
debug.cpp:7:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
    7 |  char* index_first = index(str,'c');
      |                      ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           const char*
debug.cpp:9:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
    9 |  char* index_last = rindex(str,'c');
      |                     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           const char*
```

Then I checked this program online, every function defines of `index` and `rindex` I saw are the same:

```
char* index(const char* s,int c);
char* rindex(const char* s,int c);
```

And heres my debug code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char* str = "abcdefgabcdefg";
    char* index_first = index(str,'c');
    printf("the first index is %ld\n",index_first - str + 1);
    char* index_last = rindex(str,'c');
    printf("the last index is %ld\n",index_last - str + 1);
    return 0;
 }
```

I compile it using:

```
g++ -o debug debug.cpp -std=c++17
```

I want to know why can't I do that and the right way to use `index` and `rindex` functions  and (or) the right function defines please.

Heres my environment:

```
Ubuntu LTS 20.04 (x64)
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Try `const char* index_first = index(str,'c');`, Your string.h does not seem to be conforming man pages.

Comment: POSIX.1-2008 removes the specifications of `index()` and `rindex()`, recommending `strchr()` and `strrchr()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign returned pointers  of the type `const char *` that are used within the functions to pointers of the type `char *`

Actually the functions you are calling are declared like

```
const char* index(const char* s,int c);
const char* rindex(const char* s,int c);
```

In C++ the functions can be overloaded like

```
const char* index(const char* s,int c);
const char* rindex(const char* s,int c);
```

and

```
char* index(char* s,int c);
char* rindex(char* s,int c);
```

the same way as some other standard C functions as for example the standard C function `strchr`.

So you should write

```
const char* index_first = index(str,'c');
printf("the first index is %td\n",index_first - str + 1);
const char* index_last = rindex(str,'c');
printf("the last index is %td\n",index_last - str + 1);
```

The result of subtracting two pointers has the signed integer type `ptrdiff_t`. So you need to use the conversion specifier `%td` instead of `%ld`.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **t     Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a ptrdiff_t** or the corresponding unsigned integer
> type argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a
> pointer to a ptrdiff_t argument.